# How can I parse time based tokens in JavaScript/Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, time, difference, abbreviation

I am trying to currently create a Discord bot which does temporary banning and for the most part I know how to handle this. The only issue is that I can't figure out how I would use an argument like `3w/2w/1y/etc` to convert to a new time to create a timer. I've crawled all over Google to find an answer and I can't find even a slight hint or tip on how to accomplish this, maybe you guys might be able to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a regex to parse the argument, and then map it to a date via milliseconds:

```js
const mapping = {
  w: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
  d: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
  // whatever other units you want
};

const toDate = (string) => {
  const match = string.match(/(?<number>[0-9]*)(?<unit>[a-z]*)/);
  if (match) {
    const {number, unit} = match.groups;
    const offset = number * mapping[unit];
    return new Date(Date.now() + offset);
  }
}
```

Examples:

```
> toDate('3w')
2020-09-08T19:04:15.743Z
> toDate('2d')
2020-08-20T19:04:20.622Z
```

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the argument into milliseconds, log the current `Date.now()` and check the difference to a new `Date.now()` with a certain update rate.

If the time difference is less, the user is still banned, else the user is to be unbanned.

Comment: I'm looking more specifically to parse the argument and generate a new updated time based on the provided argument.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) libaray
`npm install date-fns`

And then use the formatDistance function

`formatDistance( new Date(1986, 3, 4, 11, 32, 0), new Date(1986, 3, 4, 10, 32, 0), { addSuffix: true } ) //=> 'in about 1 hour'`

Answer (score 1):

To convert that format, replace the `h`,`d`,`w`,`m` and `y` with `x<number of seconds>`, then split it and then times the first by the second, giving you the sum in seconds.

Presuming you don't want to use a library. (which may be more robust).

Below is a few test, you would obviously need to add validation or `NaN` is likely.

```js
const shortSinceToSeconds = input => {
  var p = input
         .replace('h', 'x3600')
         .replace('d', 'x86400')
         .replace('w', 'x604800')
         .replace('m', 'x2.628e+6')
         .replace('y', 'x3.154e+7').split('x')
  return (p[0] || 0) * (p[1] || 0)
}

const test = [
  '1h', '13h', '1d', '100d', '1w', '100w', '2m', '1y'
]

//
for (let i of test) {
  console.log(`${i} = ${shortSinceToSeconds(i)} seconds`)
}
```